# create objects/instances in variables swift

Tags: swift, class, loops, variables

I don't know how to use variables when creating Instances or adressing them in Swift:
For exmaple how do I do following in a loop (creating Instances):

```
class Guest {
    let name: String
    var age: Int 
    init(name: String, age: Int) {
        self.name = name
        self.age = age
    }
}

let guests = [["ann", 1] , ["bob", 2] ...]
```

so that the loop equals :

```
let ann = Guest(name: "ann" , age: 1)
let bob = Guest(name: "bob" , age: 2)
...
```

edit: I am looking for something like this:

```
for i in guests {
  let i[0] = Guest(name: i[0] , age: i[1])
```

Example for adressing:

```
print(guests[0].age)
>>>1
```

I've searched a lot but am getting directed to issues regarding creating variables in classes.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Your question is very vague, please try to edit it so we can help you.

Comment: The loop you posted should work. Have you tried it?

Comment: @PEEJWEEJ yes I've tried, swift in terminal raises following error: repl.swift:11:10: error: consecutive statements on a line must be separated by ';'
    Where the "mistake pointer" points to  the "i[0]"  in let i[0] = ....

Comment: Oh for one. you're mutating your guests array which you can't do. You need to set it to a new array. See Charles Srstka's anwer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do that with a classic loop:

```
let input = [("Ann", 1), ("Bob", 2)]

var guests: [Guest] = []
for each in input {
    guests.append(Guest(name: each.0, age: each.1))
}
```

However, it can be done more concisely (and with avoidance of `var`) using functional techniques:

`let guests = [("Ann", 1), ("Bob", 2)].map { Guest(name: $0.0, age: $0.1) }`

EDIT: Dictionary-based solution (Swift 4; for Swift 3 version just use the classic loop)

```
let input = [("Ann", 1), ("Bob", 2)]
let guests = Dictionary(uniqueKeysWithValues: input.map {
    ($0.0, Guest(name: $0.0, age: $0.1))
})
```

Or, if it's possible for two guests to have the same name:

```
let guests = Dictionary(input.map { ($0.0, Guest(name: $0.0, age: $0.1)) }) { first, second in
    // put code here to choose which of two conflicting guests to return
    return first
}
```

With the dictionary, you can just do:

```
if let annsAge = guests["Ann"]?.age {
    // do something with the value
}
```

Comment: I would ditch the foreach loop altogether

Comment: I wanted to demonstrate the increased conciseness of the functional approach via the contrast.

Comment: Close :)  - but i still don't have  Ann.age

Comment: Huh? Yes, you do, with both of them.

Comment: print(Ann.age) gives me "error: use of unresolved identifier 'Ann' "  I can only do print(guests[0].age) -or?

Comment: Yes, you access it via array subscripts. Are you asking to generate variable names based on an array? Because that's not possible in Swift, although if what you want is to look the guests up by name, you could always store them in a dictionary.

Comment: @CharlesSrstka thank you very much, included that in the Question

Comment: Added an edit with a dictionary-based solution for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
   //MARK: Call method to create multiple instances 

createInstance([("Ann", 1), ("Bob", 2)])

func createInstance(_ input: Array<Guest>) {        
    for each in input {
        guests.append(Guest(name: each.0, age: each.1))
    }
}
```