# Calling a Function to Set a Label for a Member of a Class

Tags: ios, swift

I have a collection of posts in `UITableView cells`. I  have made a function so that when you click a `cell`, you go to a new `UIViewController`. Now I want the new `UIViewController` to update the main text and title based on the post you clicked. I have the following text for the new UIViewController:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
class MainTextView: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var titleText: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var mainText: UILabel!

    func setMain(post:Post){
        titleText.text = post.text
        mainText.text = post.title
    }
}
```

And the following text for my Home View Controller:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
    let row = indexPath.row
    print("Row: \(row)")
    let destination = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainTextView") as! MainTextView
    navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
    destination.setMain(post: posts[indexPath.row])
}
```

}

Here is my Post class:

import Foundation

class Post {
    var id:String
    var title: String
    var text:String
    var createdAt:Date

```
init(id: String, title: String,text:String,  timestamp:Double) {
    self.id = id
    self.title = title
    self.text = text
    self.createdAt = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: timestamp / 1000)

}
```

}

I should note that I also get the following error in my HomeViewController function fetchPost:

```
 func fetchPosts(completion:@escaping (_ posts:[Post])->()) {
    let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
    var queryRef:DatabaseQuery
    let lastPost = posts.last
    if lastPost != nil {
        let lastTimestamp = lastPost!.createdAt.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
        queryRef = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryEnding(atValue: lastTimestamp).queryLimited(toLast: 20)
    } else {
        queryRef = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryLimited(toLast: 20)
    }

    queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { snapshot in
        var tempPosts = [Post]()

        for child in snapshot.children {
            if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                let title = dict["text"] as? String,

                let text = dict["title"] as? String,
                let timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? Double {

                if childSnapshot.key != lastPost?.id {
                    let post = Post(id: childSnapshot.key, title: title, text: text, timestamp:timestamp)
                    tempPosts.insert(post, at: 0)
                }

            }
        }

        return completion(tempPosts)
    })
}
```

Here is my fetchPosts function:

```
func fetchPosts(completion: @escaping( _ posts:[Post])->()) {

        let postsRef = Database.database().reference().child("posts")
        let lastPost = self.posts.last
        var queryRef:DatabaseQuery

        if lastPost == nil {
            queryRef = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryLimited(toLast: 10)
        } else{
           let lastTimestamp = lastPost!.createdAt.timeIntervalSince1970 * 1000
            queryRef = postsRef.queryOrdered(byChild: "timestamp").queryEnding(atValue: lastTimestamp)
        }


        queryRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {snapshot in

            var tempPosts = [Post]()

            for child in snapshot.children {
                if let childSnapshot = child as? DataSnapshot,
                    let dict = childSnapshot.value as? [String:Any],
                    let text = dict["text"] as? String,
                    let comment = dict["comment"] as? Array<String>,
                    let title = dict["title"] as? String,
                    let timestamp = dict["timestamp"] as? Double{
                    if childSnapshot.key != lastPost?.id {
                        let post = Post(id: childSnapshot.key, title: text, text: title, comment: comment, timestamp: timestamp)
                        tempPosts.insert(post, at: 0)
                    }

                }
            }
            return completion(tempPosts)

        })



    }
```

Comment: `destination.setMain(post: somePost)`.

Comment: I replaced setMain(post:Post) with destination.setMain(post:Post). I got the error: Cannot convert value of type 'Post.Type' to expected argument type 'Post'. I'm a bit confused by what you meant here. I also tried somePost and got an error... Thank you for the help

Comment: I put `somePost` because you need to pass some instance of a `Post` object.

Comment: It looks like you are right! I need to learn about instances. This looks like a good start: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45989491/create-objects-instances-in-variables-swift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change logic of your **MainTextView** controller:

```
import UIKit
import Firebase

class MainTextView: UIViewController {

  // MARK: - Your properties

  @IBOutlet weak var titleText: UILabel!

  @IBOutlet weak var mainText: UILabel!

  var post: Post?

  // MARK: - View Controller LifeCycle

  override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    self.setMain()
  }

  private func setMain() {
      guard let post = self.post else {
          return
      }

      titleText.text = post.text
      mainText.text = post.title
  }
}
```

Also you should change logic of controller

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)

  if let destination = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier:"MainTextView") as? MainTextView {
      destination.post = <list of post>[indexPath.row]
      navigationController?.pushViewController(destination, animated: true)
  }
}
```

If you use segues in your project, you can try this decision:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, animated: true)
  performSegue(withIdentifier: "Your segue name", sender: self)
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if segue.identifier == "Your segue name", let destination = segue.destination as? MainTextView {
        destination.post = <Your selected post>
    }
}
```

Comment: When you write <Your selected post> what exactly do you mean? I just want the point (user generated) that corresponds to the given index. I would appreciate some clarity here.

Comment: This one worked! Thanks so much. Still curious about your alternative solution with segues... Also, how would you suggest making comments for the posts?

Answer (score -1):

Pass

```
destination.setMain(post: Post)
```

Because the function is located in the destination class and not the `HomeViewController`